# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _SimpleITK. Can't find the given module

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, pip, simpleitk

I am trying to use the following script provided through GitHub: [Script](https://github.com/MIC-DKFZ/LIDC-IDRI-processing). I have python 3.9.10 installed, pip version 22.0.4. But when I run `py script.py` I get the following error message: "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _SimpleITK. Can't find the given module"

I first had a problem downloading SimpleITK because CMake could not build it, or recognise the building wheel. But now that seems to work fine and I've tried using different versions of SimpleITK (2.0.2 and 2.1.0) but both give me the same error.

I also made sure to remove any other versions of python since I did have 3.10 installed before but that didn't solve anything either.

Comment: Ok I will fix that.

Comment: Do you need to build SimpleITK yourself?  You could try just doing a pip install SimpleITK.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem, I am not sure which of the steps did it but this is what I did.

Added `c:\users\alexa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages` to Path in environment variables. This is most likely the root cause of the problem.

(Re)Installed Visual Studio 2022.

Reinstalled SimpleITK, scikit-build, CMake and numpy in terminal with pip.

Comment: I'd guess it was adding the path.  Clearly Python wasn't finding the SimpleITK library.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will edit my answer so others with the same problem can find it.

Comment: If you have any other ITK/SimpleITK questions, I'd suggest the ITK discourse (discourse.itk.org).  More ITK experts would see it over there.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll be sure to use this if new problems arise with ITK!